# Using scale_size_area (ggplot2) to plot points of size "0" as completely absent

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a bubble plot of condition by cluster, where the size of each bubble is set by a third "percent" variable. As [per the ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_size.html), I think I should be able to do this via scale_size_area. I am unclear why this isn't working, and I still see very tiny points when percent=0. (If I am misunderstanding, I would also appreciate a solution on how to do this. In my real data, it is important to distinguish between 0 and very close to 0.)

```
ex <- data.frame(Condition=rep(c("ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4"),4),
                 Cluster=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4),rep(4,4)),
             Percent=c(0,0,0,1,0.25,0,0.25,0.5,1,0,0,0,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))
ggplot(ex, aes(Cluster, Condition, size=Percent))+ 
           geom_point(color = "blue")+ scale_size_area(max_size=20)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: E.g. `size=ifelse(Percent==0, NA, Percent))` instead of `size=Percent`?

Comment: It might be related to the `stroke` (the outline of the points).  Although my impression was that only points 21 through 25 had an outline, using `stroke = 0` in `geom_point` removes the points when `Percent` is 0.

Comment: @lukeA that worked! If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
library(ggplot2)
ex <- data.frame(Condition=rep(c("ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4"),4),
                 Cluster=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4),rep(4,4)),
             Percent=c(0,0,0,1,0.25,0,0.25,0.5,1,0,0,0,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25))
ggplot(ex, aes(Cluster, Condition, size=ifelse(Percent==0, NA, Percent))))+ 
           geom_point(color = "blue")+ scale_size_area(max_size=20)
```

Using `size=ifelse(Percent==0, NA, Percent))` instead of `size=Percent` will exclude those points from drawing.

Comment: This is an approximate work-around, but ```ggplot``` still interprets the value zero as a non-zero circle, so other size values above this are still slightly incorrect in their size.  This work-around might be close enough that one cannot visually distinguish the error, but it does not actually fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following, using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
ex2<-as.data.table(ex)
ggplot(ex2, aes(Cluster, Condition))+ 
geom_point(data=ex2[ex2$Percent > 0],aes(size=Percent), color = "blue")+scale_size_area(max_size=20)
```

Here you simply create a new frame within the geom_point excluding all rows with percent equal to 0.
The problem with the approach before is: if all your rows have percent equal to zero, say

```
Percent=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

You will get an error

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
>     nicht-endlicher Ort oder/und Größe des Viewports

If you use the data-table approach (or any other, that gives ggplot just the information you want to be drawed), you dont have any problems and you'll get just an empty plot, which, in case of an automated script is better than a crash.